# Why is this sequence not in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum

> Why is this sequence $1, 30, 105, 248, 264, 714, \ldots$ not in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%2030%2C%20105%2C%20248%2C%20264%2C%20714&language=english&go=Search)?

I got that sequence from this [ProofWiki link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integers_whose_Ratio_between_Sigma_and_Phi_is_Square).

I also did some further searching via Google and found these two papers in the [JOURNAL OF INTEGER SEQUENCES](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/):

[On the Ratio of the Sum of Divisors and Euler’s Totient Function I](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Broughan/broughan26.html)

[On the Ratio of the Sum of Divisors and Euler's Totient Function II](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Broughan/bro32.html)

Comment: Maybe because no one has submitted it. Why don't you?

Comment: Done submitting the sequence to OEIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Lord Shark the Unknown commented, it could be a good idea you submit it to $OEIS$.

For the fun of it, I computed the next terms which are
$$1,14,30,105,248,264,418,714,1485,3080,3135,3596,3828,3956,4064,5396,6678,8636,10098,12648,20026,20790,21318,22152,23374,24882,25714,26048,35074,35343,39105,41656,43890,44660,49938,55154,56134,56536,61344,71145,74613,86304,87087,94944$$

Comment: Okay, thanks @ClaudeLeibovici!  Will do.

Comment: Done submitting the sequence to OEIS.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris. Let me know when it appears. Cheers.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, @ClaudeLeibovici, but the sequence has already appeared in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A293391).